# Stop Akka stream Source when web socket connection is closed by the client

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have an [akka http web socket](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/websocket-support.html) `Route` with a code similar to:

private val wsReader: Route =
    path("v1" / "data" / "ws") {
      log.info("Opening websocket connecting ...")

```
  val testSource = Source
    .repeat("Hello")
    .throttle(1, 1.seconds)
    .map(x => {
      println(x)
      x
    })
    .map(TextMessage.Strict)
    .limit(1000)

  extractUpgradeToWebSocket { upgrade ⇒
    complete(upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(Sink.ignore, testSource))
  }
}
```

Everything works fine (I receive from the client 1 test message every second). The only problem is that I don't understand how to stop/close the `Source` (`testSource`) if the client close the web socket connection.

You can see that the source continue to produce elements (see `println`) also if the web socket is down.

How can I detect a client disconnection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

handleMessagesWithSinkSource is implemented as:

```
/**
 * The high-level interface to create a WebSocket server based on "messages".
 *
 * Returns a response to return in a request handler that will signal the
 * low-level HTTP implementation to upgrade the connection to WebSocket and
 * use the supplied inSink to consume messages received from the client and
 * the supplied outSource to produce message to sent to the client.
 *
 * Optionally, a subprotocol out of the ones requested by the client can be chosen.
 */
def handleMessagesWithSinkSource(
  inSink:      Graph[SinkShape[Message], Any],
  outSource:   Graph[SourceShape[Message], Any],
  subprotocol: Option[String]                   = None): HttpResponse =

  handleMessages(Flow.fromSinkAndSource(inSink, outSource), subprotocol)
```

This means the sink and the source are independent, and indeed the source should keep producing elements even when the client closes the incoming side of the connection. It should stop when the client resets the connection completely, though.

To stop producing outgoing data as soon as the incoming connection is closed, you may use `Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled`, so:

```
val socket = upgrade.handleMessages(
  Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled(inSink, outSource)
  subprotocol = None
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Very clean solution!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [KillSwitches](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-dynamic.html) to handle testSource shutdown.

```
private val wsReader: Route =
path("v1" / "data" / "ws") {
  logger.info("Opening websocket connecting ...")

  val sharedKillSwitch = KillSwitches.shared("my-kill-switch")

  val testSource =
    Source
     .repeat("Hello")
     .throttle(1, 1.seconds)
     .map(x => {
       println(x)
       x
     })
    .map(TextMessage.Strict)
    .limit(1000)
    .via(sharedKillSwitch.flow)

  extractUpgradeToWebSocket { upgrade ⇒
    val inSink = Sink.onComplete(_ => sharedKillSwitch.shutdown())
    val outSource = testSource
    val socket = upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(inSink, outSource)

    complete(socket)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hamednourhani! Good solution. I didn't know about `KillSwitches` and the trick to use the sink to detect web socket connection.